# Passing information to a custom TableViewCell - Swift

Tags: swift, delegates, datasource, uitableview

The problem is this: I tried many ways to pass down information to a ViewController1 from a SecondViewController. In this first ViewController1 I have a tableView, and in this tableView, each cell will receive an image and a label. What I want to do is, in the SecondViewController, I will write something in a textField and pick some random image and display it in the ViewController1.

Could someone tell me how to do it? I tried delegates, dequeuereusablecell and the data won't display in the cell.

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT**

here's my code:

ViewController 1:

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, sendDataToFVCDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!
var labelsListArray = [""]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func myVCDidFinish(text: String) {
    labelsListArray.append(text)
    tableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return labelsListArray.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let row = indexPath.row
    let textLabel = labelsListArray[row]
    var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageView") as? CustomCellTableViewCell
    cell!.cellLabel!.text = textLabel
    return cell!
}
```

}

ViewController 2:

import UIKit

protocol sendDataToFVCDelegate {
    func myVCDidFinish(text: String)
}

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {

```
var delegate:sendDataToFVCDelegate?
@IBOutlet var textField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if textField == nil { return }
    let name = textField.text
    println("\(name)")

    if delegate == nil { return }
    delegate?.myVCDidFinish(name)

    if let navigation = self.navigationController {
        navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

}

TableViewCell :

import UIKit

class CustomCellTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

```
@IBOutlet var cellImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet var cellLabel: UILabel!



override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code
}

override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}
```

}

What am I doing wrong? Now even the line "popViewControllerAnimated" is going back to the first view controller.

Thanks very much for your help!!

Comment: Using the delegate pattern is correct. Post your code so we can see what went wrong.

Comment: I deleted my entire code. Could post any simple example on how to do it? Maybe I missed a detail or anything. I would be very greatfull

Comment: I have a simple project that does something similar to what you need: https://github.com/maurovz/MarvelAPIExample

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So your custom TableViewCell should have it's own class (for example `ImageTableViewCell`) which takes care of the image you will set when loading the TableView:

```
@IBOutlet var titleLabel: UILabel!
@IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!
```

and in the TableView:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("ImageView") as? ImageTableViewCell
        cell!.titleLabel!.text = textFrom2VC
        cell!.imageView.image = imageFrom2VC
        return cell!
}
```

And you have to get these from the other view with delegate. In the second VC you have

```
protocol SecondVCDelegate{
    func myVCDidFinish(controller:SecondVC, text: String, image: UIImage)
}
```

which you call with

```
    var delegate:SecondVCDelegate.myVCDidFinish(self, text: "this is random text", image: (your image) )
```

and in the first (which confirms to protocol SecondVCDelegate) you have

```
func myVCDidFinish(controller: SecondVC, text: String, image: UIImage) {
    textFrom2VC = text
    imageFrom2VC = image
    controller.navigationController?.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: You set the delegate to optional which makes it nil and then you are only setting it if it is **not** nil, which doesn't make any sense. So if you delete the `if delegate == nil { return }` I think it should work...

Comment: You were right. The addButton does work now, what I wrote is printed in the log but the string does not go to the label, it is still empty. Any idea why?