# Delegating a string to a UILabel and an image to a UIImageView - Swift

Tags: iphone, swift, core-data, uiimageview, delegates

So, this is what's happening: I have two controllers; MainViewController and DetailsTableViewController. On DetailsTableViewController I want to write a name for random recipe, then I pick an image from photo library. After that, I want to send those data to a cell in MainViewController. The code this:

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

class MainViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, sendDetailsToMVCDelegate {


    @IBOutlet weak var mainImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
    var namesListArray: [String] = []
    var imagesListArray: [UIImage] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
    }

    func sendDetailsToMVC (name: String, image: UIImage) {
        namesListArray.append(name)
        imagesListArray.append(image)
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return namesListArray.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var row = indexPath.row
        var name: String = namesListArray[row] as String
        var image: UIImage = imagesListArray[row] as UIImage
        var cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("customCell") as! CustomCellTableViewCell
        cell.customLabel!.text = (name as String)
        cell.customImage.image = (image as UIImage)
        return cell
     }
}
```

and

```
import UIKit
import CoreData

protocol sendDetailsToMVCDelegate {
    func sendDetailsToMVC(name: String, image: UIImage)
}

class DetailsViewController: UIViewController, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate, sendNameToDetailsViewControllerDelegate {


@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var recipeImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
var ingredientsList = [""]
var delegateDetails: sendDetailsToMVCDelegate?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let howToDoButton = UIBarButtonItem(title:"How To Do", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: Selector("showHowToDoScreen"))
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = howToDoButton
    let newIngredientButton = UIBarButtonItem(title:"New Ingredient", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target:self, action: Selector("showNewIngredientScreen"))
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = newIngredientButton

    //Picker imagem pelo toque
    let tapGestureRecognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "chooseImage:")
    tapGestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired = 1
    recipeImage.addGestureRecognizer(tapGestureRecognizer)
    recipeImage.userInteractionEnabled = true

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    return ingredientsList.count
}

func addNameToDetailsViewController(nameToDetail: NSString) {
    ingredientsList.append(nameToDetail as String)
    if tableView == nil {
        return
    }
    tableView!.reloadData()
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let row = indexPath.row
    let ingredientName = ingredientsList[row]
    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: nil)
    cell.textLabel!.text = ingredientName
    return cell

}

//Picka a imagem pelo toque, acessando a PhotoLibrary
func chooseImage(recognizer: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    let imagePicker: UIImagePickerController = UIImagePickerController()
    imagePicker.delegate = self
    imagePicker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary
    self.presentViewController(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

//Ao selecionar a imagem, coloca-a na tela tocada
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject:AnyObject]) {
    let pickedImage: UIImage = (info as NSDictionary).objectForKey(UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage) as! UIImage
    // small picture
    let smallPicture = scaleImageWith(pickedImage, newSize: CGSizeMake(75,75))
    var sizeOfImageView:CGRect = recipeImage.frame
    sizeOfImageView.size = smallPicture.size
    recipeImage.frame = sizeOfImageView
    recipeImage.image = smallPicture
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}


func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(picker: UIImagePickerController) {
    picker.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}

func scaleImageWith(image:UIImage, newSize: CGSize) -> UIImage {
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(newSize, false, 0.0)
    image.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0,0, newSize.width, newSize.height))
    let newImage: UIImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
    return newImage
}

@IBAction func showNewIngredientScreen() {
    let newIngredient = AddIngredientViewController(delegate: self)
        if let navigation = navigationController {
           navigation.pushViewController(newIngredient, animated: true)
        }
    }

@IBAction func showHowToDoScreen() {
    let howToDo = HowToDoViewController(nibName: "HowToDoViewController", bundle: nil)
    if let navigation = navigationController {
        navigation.pushViewController(howToDo, animated: true)
    }
}



@IBAction func addButton(sender: AnyObject) {

    if nameTextField == nil || recipeImage == nil { return }
    if recipeImage == nil { return }

    let nameLabel = nameTextField.text
    let imageView = recipeImage.image

    if delegateDetails == nil { return }
    delegateDetails?.sendDetailsToMVC(nameLabel, image: imageView!)

    println("button pressed, name \(nameLabel) and image \(imageView) added.")

    if let navigation = self.navigationController {
        navigation.popViewControllerAnimated(true)
    }
}
```

My question is: am I passing the information correctly? Is the correct way for storing images creating images arrays like I did? When I press the addButton, nothing happens, but it has no crashes. I'm in this issue for quite some time already and I would be very thankful if someone pointed to me what's wrong.

By the way, I'm new to Swift, so forgive me for any n00b mistakes.

Thanks!

Comment: I managed to make the addButton work deleting the if delegate == nil { return } but the text and the image still don't go to the first view controller, it remains empty. Anyone has any idea why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should be the same as in your [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30563205/passing-information-to-a-custom-tableviewcell-swift/). In the `addButton` function you are only setting the delegate if not `nil`and not if you should. So delete `if delegateDetails == nil { return }` from the DetailViewControler - addButton and it should work.

Comment: It does work, but the image and the text still dont go to the label and the imageview in the first viewcontroller. Do you know why?

Comment: you missed the `tableView.reloadAllComponents()` in the `sendDetailsToMVC(...)`

Comment: It seems that there is no .reloaAllComponents(). I tried tableView.reloadData() and it didn't work either. I'm very confused! It seems it won't work anyway :(

Comment: Sorry, `reloadAllComponents` is for pickerView and `.reloadData` is correct for the tableView...

Comment: Try to print the content you get in the `sendDetailsToMVC`. Is everything working if you move the data to the first VC?

Comment: Yes it does work. The log shows what I typed in the text field and the image I picked in the photo library, but it does not show in the first vc. What are we missing? 

Comment: And the arrays got these aswell?

Comment: Yes! I tried everything I knew already. The app works properly, only this part went wrong. Image and label does not update

Comment: Does the `tableView: numberOfRowsInSection` function get called if you go back? By the way: if you upload your code to github I could look in the code and check a few things

Comment: I don't know how to check if it gets called. I can upload it, I'll make an account on github and let you know when it's uploaded.

Comment: Put a `println(namesListArray)` into the function would be an idea

Comment: Github has some nice features if used correct: you have a history for each document (see your deleted `delegate`-method) and you can always go back to a working version. Only thing to do: add the repository to Xcode and then you can commit (save a snapshot of current content) and push this commit directly from Xcode.

Comment: https://github.com/nicholaspiccoli/iRecipeList here it is. Finally haha! Now tell me that the heck is going on, please!

Comment: I am not allowed to change your code but you have to enter this in your MainViewController:   `override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
        if segue.identifier == "newReciep" {
            var vc = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailsViewController
            vc.delegateDetails = self
        }
    }`
 and you have to name the segue from the main view to the addReciep view "newReciep"

Comment: You never set the `delegateDetails` so it was nil and if you then do `delegateDetails?.sendDetailsToMVC()`it will ignore it because there is no such function in nil...

Comment: I just created a pull request in github. You can accept it and then pull the new version to your local repository

Comment: So, I downloaded the file you modified. I saw that you set a prepareForSegue function and set it in the storyboard. But when I run the app, it still doesn't send the image and the text to the first view controller. Should I modify something as well?

Comment: There is something I'm not setting right, and I don't have any idea what that is :/